# How to use CMake to download specific header file from git to create a new interface target?

Tags: c++, cmake, configuration, external-project

I'm not sure if this is even the right command, but every google search brings me back to `ExternalProject_Add`.  I thought, based on the documentation, that the only thing I would have to do to download a specific file from a git repository would be to specify the URL.  But that doesn't appear to work.

I'm trying to extract the headeronly library found in https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(vma-external
        URL https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator/blob/master/src/vk_mem_alloc.h
        SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/VulkanMemoryAllocator"
        DOWNLOAD_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/VulkanMemoryAllocator"
        BUILD_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
)

add_library(vma INTERFACE)
add_dependencies(vma vma-external)
target_include_directories(vma SYSTEM INTERFACE external/VulkanMemoryAllocator)
```

Underneath the ["Download Step Options"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) it appeared as if merely specifying the URL would tell CMake to grab that file. What I end up with is a new empty directory (VulkanMemoryAllocator) but no CMake errors. I'm not really sure what I need to do.  The examples in the CMake documentation seem to imply I don't even need to go as far as I'm going here to get anything to significant to happen (for example):

```
find_program(MAKE_EXE NAMES gmake nmake make)
ExternalProject_Add(secretsauce
  URL               http://intranet.somecompany.com/artifacts/sauce-2.7.tgz
                    https://www.somecompany.com/downloads/sauce-2.7.zip
  URL_HASH          MD5=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ${MAKE_EXE} sauce
)
```

I don't have a URL_HASH or a build command for mine (since it is header only). I just want CMake to get the file, so I can create the interface target.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing happens until you build the project.  But your assumptions are incorrect because the URL keyword assumes an archive.  The URL you are using is to a webpage and causes errors to occur in the build process.  Since you don't want to download the entire GIT via GIT_REPOSITORY you might want to use the `file(DOWNLOAD)` command directly to download the file.  You'll have to use the correct URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator/master/src/vk_mem_alloc.h

```
file(DOWNLOAD
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator/master/src/vk_mem_alloc.h
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/VulkanMemoryAllocator/vk_mem_alloc.h)
```

Comment: Is there any way to select individual files from the ExternalProject_Add GIT api so I can depend on certain branches of the file? and how do I deal with updates on the file?  I'm not sure how I create a target from the download itself or check for updated information.

Comment: @whn Nothing is mentioned in the documentation; so I'd say no. Last time I tried git sparse checkouts this didn't work out so well.  My opinion is that git doesn't handle this use case well.  It's probably by far easier / faster to use ExternalProject_Add with git and fetch the whole repos.